# Time taken for sliding mass to fall down

Tags: friction

[image]

Figure shows a small block of mass m kept at the left end of a larger block of mass M and length l.

The system can slide on a horizontal road. The system is started towards right with an intial velocity v. The friction coefficient between the road and the bigger block is µ and that between the blocks is µ/2.

Find the time elapsed before the smaller block separates from the bigger block.
Guys,I drew the free body diagrams for the small and the larger mass,but I couldnt solve the problem.It is complicated and I am not able to understand.Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Hello. Your free body diagram isn't in accordance with your worded question. I see $M$ for a small block on top of an unmarked larger block. $m$ doesn't feature in your diagram. And as this is a homework-style question you're required to show your attempt at solving , no matter how partial that attempt may be.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE.  Feel free to look around, and please take the tour (under 'help' on the top menu bar). As noted, this has all the appearances of a homework-type problem, since you have given no indication of how you have approached the problem and the physics that you have gotten stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

Normal force between blocks will be $ N_1 = mg $ and the normal force between the road and the larger block will be $ N_2 = ( m + M ) g $. So the friction forces are,
$$ F_1 = {\mu \over 2} N_1 = {\mu \over 2} m g $$
$$ F_2 = \mu N_2 = \mu ( m + M ) g $$
The total force on the bigger block will be $ F_1 + F_2 $ to the left. So the larger block will decelerate at rate
$$ a_2 = {F \over M} = {(F_1 + F_2) \over M} = \mu g \left(  { 3m \over 2M } + 1 \right) $$
Let's work in the rest frame of the larger block. In this frame, the smaller block will have acceleration to right equal to $ a_2 $ in addition to its acceleration due to forces acting on it. Acceleration due to forces is $ a_1 = F_1 / m = {1 \over 2} \mu g $ and this acceleration is directed towards left. Since $ a_2 $ is directed towards right, the total acceleration of the smaller block (in the rest frame of the larger block) is
$$ a = a_2 - a_1 = {\mu g \over 2} \left(  { 3m \over M } + 1 \right) $$
At the initial moment, the velocity of the blocks relative to each other is $0$. Accordingly, the equation for the time it takes for the smaller block to fall off the other block, $t$ is,
$$ {1 \over 2} a t^2 = l $$
$$ t = \sqrt { 2l \over a } = \sqrt { 4l \over { \mu g \left(  { 3m \over M } + 1 \right) }} $$

This should be the answer, though I may have made an error as I had to type this quickly and made calculations in my head. Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe your answer is incorrect. The OP states that the system starts moving right with an **initial velocity** $v$. He states no _net force_ or acceleration acting on the system. Without either, there’s no inertial force acting on the small block, it’s travelling at constant speed $v$. Compare it to a mug of tea standing on a table in a train travelling at constant speed: does the mug slide off the table? **No**. The force you name $F_1$ would be a reactive friction force, if some force $F$ was acting on that block but at constant speed there is no such force $F$.

Comment: Of course it’s possible that some acceleration took place to get from $0$ to $v$ but the OP hasn’t specified anything of the sort: no time interval or acceleration, so that part of the problem is undefined. I think the OP hasn’t thought out his problem very well.

Comment: Oh. I see now where **I am wrong**: the lower block does of course decelerate. My bad and apologies.